# Twilio Lookup API for Node.js - validate and get in E.164 format

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am trying to use the API to validate a phone number that a user provides. If the user enters an invalid phone number, I want to throw an error. If it is a valid phone number, I then want to do something with the E.164 formatted number, like add it to my db.

I know the code below is incorrect, since client.lookups returns { state: 'pending' } and not the value in phone_number.phoneNumber. Anyone know what I need to do to make this work?

```
const mobileNumber = '61 (02) 9876 5432'

const validPhone = client.lookups
                         .phoneNumbers(mobileNumber)
                         .fetch()
                         .then(phone_number => {
                            return phone_number.phoneNumber
                          })

if(!validPhone){
  throw new Error('This is an invalid phone number')
} else {
    // do something with validPhone (which I want to be the phone in E.164 format)
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what doesn't work. Is it the API, is it your code?

Anyway, it looks like you're interpreting `async` code wrong. The `validPhone` variable won't get set to what you think. It will actually be a promise. If you want to use classic promise format, then the valid phone check should happen inside the `then` block.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad - still pretty new to programming - you are right about the problem with my code, which I fixed by adding it to then block - step in the right direction. I still have a problem though. If the phone number is valid, the API returns an object which I can access in the then block. If it is not a valid phone number, then the API doesn't seem to return anything (at least nothing that I can console.log). How can I throw an error if the API doesn't return anything?

Comment: Whenever you have a `.then`, you should always have a `.catch`. Any errors that happen when executing the promise will be forwarded to the `.catch` block.

Comment: When you send an invalid number to the Twilio Lookup API it will return a 404 which is seen by the library as an error. So you will need to add a `.catch` block as Vlad suggests.